# Automated D&D with DM assistance

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons

Is there a way to automate D&D without losing the creativity?

I played an Adventurers League game where the DM kept presenting the players with choices.  For example on the "Day at the Races" we could either attack with whip or defend with shield.  Another example: we were collecting ribbons which were just dice rolls.

My point is that although it was a newbie group, a lot of my suggestions were denied.  My overly-ambitious character couldn't steal the opponents' ribbons (there was no rule in the race that disallowed this) or whip my own mount when it started to get sluggish.  It felt like I had to stick to the script.

What if the DM presented the players with lots of valid options, say 5 or 6, and the characters would decide what to do and what to roll.  This way the DM can plan ahead to some degree and speed up the game.

My issue with D&D is that there's lots of hidden options. Is there a system that plays like this?

EDIT: My issue is during a game of D&D I was very limited by what I could do as as player. This is in stark contrast to advice I was given as a DM that I could not plan ahead as players could do almost anything.

This led me to think, "What if players were presented with options or paths that the DM had already planned ahead for?". If this was the case, then the game could play out automatically like a multiplayer choose your own adventure book.

This could free up the DM to do things such as puppet the monsters or NPCs. A task I feel is more fun than doing bookkeeping.

Does such a system exist?

Comment: Are you asking about a problem with "D&D as a whole" or about "D&D Adventures League"? It matters more than you'd think.

Comment: There are a number of questions one could have about this situation (like, was the DM restricting you ok/normal, or what can you do to fix a game situation like that, or whether it's possible to have a no-DM game), but the one asked at the end here is asking for recommendations of games/systems that work a certain way, which is a question type we can't answer at RPG.se.

Comment: I edited your question for a bit of syntax and organization.  Please edit the question again and specify if you are trying to solve how Adventurers League games operate, or if you perceive a fundamental issue in D&D that you need a solution for.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @TheScando Please don't answer in comments. [Here's our meta policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments). Reserve comments for seeking clarification or suggesting improvements, or minor moderation or meta matters -- if they really just want recommendations, 4444L needs to be asking [on a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449) rather than here.